# trying to insert <script> (recaptcha) tag into a <div> and it's not working. I'm using .html()

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I'm trying to insert recaptcha code into a div and it doesn't work. nothing happens. here's the code:

```
var reCaptcha = '<'+'script type="text/javascript">var RecaptchaOptions = {theme : \'red\',tabindex : 0};<'+'/script>'+'<'+'script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdjvN8SAAAAABUppmhvNOZlq94LauQIGdQ2S042"><'+'/'+'script>'+'<'+'noscript><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdjvN8SAAAAABUppmhvNOZlq94LauQIGdQ2S042" frameborder="1"></iframe><><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"><'+'/'+'noscript>';

$('#recaptcha').html(reCaptcha);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same code work if you put it straight into your HTML (i.e. cut out the JavaScript part)?

Comment: You can't include it that way because it uses `document.write` You must include it directly in the html

Comment: You need to use this way of calling it: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX

Comment: when you call .html, is the document loaded yet? if not, try put $(function() {  and   }); around the code

Comment: Sweet! that Ajax Api worked out great. I wasted so much time on this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append a script to an html tag that executes `document.write` and expect it to work the same way it would if you included it directly in the html. Doing so after the DOM is ready may result in the entire document being replaced with the result of the `document.write`. In your situation you just need to use the AJAX api rather than the Non-AJAX api.

```
Recaptcha.create("your_public_key",
  "element_id",
  {
    theme: "red",
    callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
  }
);
```

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX